# PropertyInfo.PropertyType not annotated with DynamicallyAccessedMembersAttribute

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to make some code that uses reflection trim-friendly. I thought I could use the `DynamicallyAccessedMembersAttribute` for that, but I've hit a snag where I'm trying to access not just the members of the type, but also the types of those members.

Take the following simple example:

```cs
class Example
{
    public static void Test([DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties)] Type type)
    {
        var prop = type.GetProperty("Bar")!;
        var parseMethod = prop.PropertyType.GetMethod("Parse", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, new[] { typeof(ReadOnlySpan<char>), typeof(IFormatProvider) });
        Console.WriteLine(parseMethod);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This results in the following warning when trim analysis is enabled:

```
1>D:\Sven\Documents\Code\cstrimtest\cstrimtest\Program.cs(12,27,12,144): warning IL2075: 'this' argument does not satisfy 'DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicMethods' in call to 'System.Type.GetMethod(String, BindingFlags, Type[])'. The return value of method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.get' does not have matching annotations. The source value must declare at least the same requirements as those declared on the target location it is assigned to.
```

It seems the issue is that `PropertyInfo.PropertyType` is not annotated, and indeed this code fails if published with trimming. Is there a way to annotate the fact that I want to access the `PropertyType` and the members of that type as well? Or am I out of luck here?

Comment: https://morioh.com/p/0b46335404ab

Comment: I have exactly the same issue for now. Did you have found any solution or workaround ?